# How to pass validation query for sql server in fuse osgi environment

Tags: java, osgi, sqldatasource, jbossfuse

How to pass validation query, testonborrow, validationQueryTimeout properties to sqlserver datasource in Fuse Osgi environment? We are using osgi service to expose microsoft SQLServer datasource. Right now we are passing datasourcename, user, password, portNumber and serverName as properties to instantiate SQLServerDataSource. How can we pass validation query, testonborrow,testWhileIdle,testOnBorrow etc properties similar to Apache commons dbcp? We are seeing connection issues and we handled it by passing validationquery etc to commons dbcp and wanted to do same to SQLServer Datasource. Appreciate any help?
Here is sample how we are instantiating SQLServer Datasource and Exposing as OSGI service.

```
 <bean id="abcd" class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
        <property name="databaseName" value="datasourcename" />
        <property name="user" value="user" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
        <property name="portNumber" value="portNumber" />
        <property name="serverName" value="serverName" />
 </bean>
<!-- Opening Datasource as osgi service -->
<service interface="javax.sql.DataSource" ref="abcd">
        <service-properties>
            <entry key="osgi.jndi.service.name" value="jdbc/abcd" />
        </service-properties>
</service>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's kind of canonical example that uses non XA data source you've configured using `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 https://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd">

    <!--
        This Blueprint XML shows the _deployment_ method for data source configuration.
        With this method, it is not required to use pax-jdbc bundles at all. Instead both database-specific
        and generic data sources are declared as Blueprint beans.
        We need:
         - SQL Server driver bundle
         - mvn:org.apache.commons/commons-pool2/2.5.0 bundle
         - mvn:org.apache.commons/commons-dbcp2/2.1.1 bundle

        This Blueprint XML can be directly dropped to ${karaf.home}/deploy or archived in typical /OSGI-INF/blueprint
        directory and installed as normal bundle.
    -->

    <!--
        Database-specific, non-pooling, non-enlisting javax.sql.XADataSource
    -->
    <bean id="sqlServerDS" class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
        <property name="databaseName" value="datasourcename" />
        <property name="user" value="user" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
        <property name="portNumber" value="portNumber" />
        <property name="serverName" value="serverName" />
    </bean>

    <!--
        Non database-specific, generic, pooling, non-XA factory for javax.sql.DataSource instances
    -->
    <bean id="dataSourceConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DataSourceConnectionFactory">
        <!-- pass database-specific javax.sql.DataSource -->
        <argument ref="sqlServerDS" />
    </bean>

    <!--
        Non database-specific factory for org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnection objects
    -->
    <bean id="poolableConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory">
        <argument index="0" ref="dataSourceConnectionFactory" />
        <!-- JMX Name - not needed -->
        <argument index="1">
            <null />
        </argument>
        <property name="maxConnLifetimeMillis" value="30000" />
        <!-- set your validation query here: -->
        <property name="validationQuery" value="select schema_name, schema_owner from information_schema.schemata" />
        <!-- in seconds -->
        <property name="validationQueryTimeout" value="2" />
    </bean>

    <!--
        Pooling configuration
    -->
    <bean id="poolConfig" class="org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPoolConfig">
        <property name="minIdle" value="2" />
        <property name="maxTotal" value="10" />
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <!--
        Non database-specific pool of objects provided by PoolableConnectionFactory
    -->
    <bean id="pool" class="org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool">
        <argument index="0" ref="poolableConnectionFactory" />
        <argument index="1" ref="poolConfig" />
    </bean>

    <!--
        And findally non database-specific, generic, pooling javax.sql.DataSource
    -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource">
        <argument ref="pool" />
    </bean>

    <!--
        Expose datasource to use by application code (like Camel, Spring, ...)
    -->
    <service interface="javax.sql.DataSource" ref="dataSource">
        <service-properties>
            <entry key="osgi.jndi.service.name" value="jdbc/ds" />
        </service-properties>
    </service>

</blueprint>
```

I'm not sure if `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource` implements `javax.sql.XADataSource` - in this case it'd be easier, as you could use `org.apache.commons.dbcp2.managed.BasicManagedDataSource` and just configure it with all you need like this:

```
<bean id="pool" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.managed.BasicManagedDataSource">
    <property name="xaDataSourceInstance" ref="sqlServerDS" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="tm" />
    <property name="minIdle" value="3" />
    <property name="maxTotal" value="10" />
    <property name="validationQuery" value="select schema_name, schema_owner from information_schema.schemata" />
</bean>
```

But in this case, `sqlServerDS` should be instance of `javax.sql.XADataSource`.

EDIT: I see there are still problems described here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARIES-960

Personally it's best to create an object like this (excuse me for using PostgreSQL):

```java
package com.example;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class DataSourceFactory {

    public DataSource create() {

        // Database-specific, non-pooling, non-enlisting javax.sql.XADataSource
        org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource postgresqlDs = new org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource();
        postgresqlDs.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db");
        postgresqlDs.setUser("user");
        postgresqlDs.setPassword("password");
        postgresqlDs.setCurrentSchema("schema");
        postgresqlDs.setConnectTimeout(5);

        // Non database-specific, generic, pooling, non-XA factory for javax.sql.DataSource instances
        org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DataSourceConnectionFactory dataSourceConnectionFactory
                = new org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DataSourceConnectionFactory(postgresqlDs);

        // Non database-specific factory for org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnection objects
        org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory poolableConnectionFactory
                = new org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory(dataSourceConnectionFactory, null);
        poolableConnectionFactory.setMaxConnLifetimeMillis(30000);
        poolableConnectionFactory.setValidationQuery("select schema_name, schema_owner from information_schema.schemata");
        poolableConnectionFactory.setValidationQueryTimeout(2);

        // Pooling configuration
        org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPoolConfig poolConfig
                = new org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPoolConfig();
        poolConfig.setMinIdle(2);
        poolConfig.setMaxTotal(10);
        poolConfig.setTestOnBorrow(true);

        // Non database-specific pool of objects provided by PoolableConnectionFactory
        org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool<org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnection> pool
                = new org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool<>(poolableConnectionFactory, poolConfig);

        // And finally non database-specific, generic, pooling javax.sql.DataSource
        org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource<org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnection> dataSource
                = new org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource<>(pool);

        return dataSource;
    }

}
```

And the use simpler blueprint like this:

```
<bean id="factory" class="com.example.DataSourceFactory">
    <!-- You can configure properties for your factory here -->
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" factory-ref="factory" factory-method="create" />

<service interface="javax.sql.DataSource" ref="dataSource">
    <service-properties>
        <entry key="osgi.jndi.service.name" value="jdbc/ds" />
    </service-properties>
</service>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried as you suggested and  facing following error. Does this ring any bell? org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Unable to find a matching constructor on class org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool for arguments [org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe$UnwrapperedBeanHolder@c8114d2, org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe$UnwrapperedBeanHolder@6e7ded67] when instanciating bean pool

Comment: give me a moment - I'll try to check

Comment: Thank you, Did you get a chance to look into this?

Comment: Hi - I updated the answer - after EDIT. Suggesting that the problem https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARIES-960 is not yet resolved. Also I added a code sample with "object factory" pattern.